# how to encode array in json with keys only in PHP

Tags: php, json

i have fetched a single row which contains two attributes say  `email_id` and `first_name` from the database in PHP. Now i am encoding this data using `json_encode($data,128)`. It is converting the data to json format. I am getting array in format like

```
{
    "0": "example@example.com",
    "1": "Sahil Manchanda",
    "email_id": "example@example.com",
    "first_name": "Sahil Manchanda"
}
```

but i want only

```
{
       "email_id": "example@example.com",
        "first_name": "Sahil Manchanda"
}
```

My php code to fetch data is

```
 $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT  'email_id','first_name'  FROM `customer` WHERE `username`=?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $username); 
        try {
            $query->execute();
            $data = $query->fetch();
            return $data;
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
```

May you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: You need to do `fetch_assoc`, not `fetch_array`. Supply your php code, the issue is in there.

Comment: @Darren So i should replace fetch() with fetch_assoc()?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off the `PHP` code you posted, you're best to use the following to fetch the data the following way:

```
$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Alternatively, you could simply do:

```
$query->fetch_object();
```

To get an object (fetching the data as: `FETCH_OBJ`)

---

[Read more about `PDO->fetch()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) (<sup>*Make sure to check out the `fetch_style` section for more information.*</sup>)

Comment: Notice: Use of undefined constant FETCH_ASSOC - assumed 'FETCH_ASSOC' in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\core\classes\Customer.class.php on line 42

Warning: PDOStatement::fetch() expects parameter 1 to be long, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\app\core\classes\Customer.class.php on line 42

Comment: Don't wrap `FETCH_ASSOC` with commas (`'`)

Comment: i got the error please update your answer with $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

Comment: Apologies, it's been a long day and I've drank too much already haha